# Send a file with webpy and urllib2

Tags: python, web.py

I need to send a file to another server using oauth and webpy. For now I'll ignore the oauth part as sending the file itself is already a challenge.

Here's my partial code:

```
class create_video:
  def POST(self):
    x = web.input(video_original={})
```

At this point I want to send the file over the network using urllib2. Note that I also have other parameters to send.

**UPDATE**

considering that I want to send these parameters:

```
params = {
  'title': x['title'],
  'video_original': x['video_original'].file
}
```

How do I use urllib2 (or anything else) to send them to a given url?

P.S. I've tried to use the poster module but I don't know how to send generic parameters along with the file.

Comment: Please include links where possible.  By "poster module", presumably you mean this one: http://atlee.ca/software/poster/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're coming from [here](http://webpy.org/cookbook/fileupload), I guess.

The `POST` method defines how to receive data via POST requests, rather than send any data. In your code, the data from an incoming POST request is saved in `x`. How do you want to proceed now? If you want to send the data to another url, use urllib(2) as described [here](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen).